# How can I open and run .java files in eclipse?

Tags: java

I have to work with a bunch of small applets that were sent to me in a folder, all of them are .java files. In order to see which part of the code is responsible for a particular outcome I want to open it in eclipse and run it there too. How can I do this?

I have tried copying the code into a new eclipse window, but it could not run it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.java files are pure text files, create java project in eclipse and copy the files there.

Comment: Thank you for the advice.
I tried creating a new project and now all the programs and folders appear in eclipse on the right, but it still gives error messages when I run them. The codes are good for sure, because I was able to run them on another computer, where the system automatically opened them the right way.